# Data Labels in histogram using GGplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Here I am trying to able to plot the graph with the below two lines of code.

```
ggplot(Melvyl,aes(x=Type.of.Customer)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

[image: This is the graph i am getting]

But I want data labels or the count on each of the category, trying the below code but its not working. can you please help me out!
Thank you

```
ggplot(Melvyl,aes(x=Type.of.Customer)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="count")+  stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1.5)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `geom_histogram` you could go on with `geom_bar`. To add your labels use `geom_text` with `stat="count"`.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat = "count", vjust=-1.5)
```

[image]